# Pass different variables to modals based on the button that opened it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm building an app in Rails and I a using foundation.

I have three buttons which are opening the same modal and I'm passing a local inside, it works fine. However, I would like to know which button opened the modal and I want to show it inside the partial.

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="modal" id="modal-opener-0">
  Open Modal 0
</a>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="modal" id="modal-opener-1">
  Open Modal 1
</a>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="modal" id="modal-opener-2">
  Open Modal 2
</a>

<div id="modal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal role="dialog">
  <%= render partial: "modal-content", locals: { name: @name } %>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Is this possible to know without js? I could make three different modals, but I was wondering if this can be achieved with only one.

Can I pass locals from link to modal and then pass it to the partial?

Comment: can you please check this https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html

Comment: I think you need some javascript

Comment: It need js or one modal per button...